# Cannot define function of type enum which is declared (public) in base class in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have this base class

```
#ifndef _VEHICLE_H_
#define _VEHICLE_H_

#include <iostream>

class Vehicle {
public:
    enum class Err_Status {
        Err_Success,
        Err_Out_Of_Fuel, //TODO: Complete for out of fuel, fuel overflow, and incorrect mode
        Err_Fuel_Overflow,
        Err_Incorrect_Mode
    };
    //TODO: Add function interfaces for travel, add fuel, get fuel and get cost.
    virtual Err_Status Travel(double _distance) = 0; //Travel takes distance as an argument and returns an error status
    virtual Err_Status AddFuel(double _amount) = 0;  //AddFuel takes amount as an argument and returns an error status
    virtual double GetFuel() = 0;                    //GetFuel simply returns the amount of fuel left in the tank
    virtual double GetCost() = 0;                   //GetCost simply returns the accumulated cost of all fuel purchases
};

#endif// _VEHICLE_H_
```

and I have this derived class  Automobile I have declared this in file Automobile.h

```
class Automobile : public Vehicle {
    //TODO: Add variables for name, fuel efficiency (L per 100km), fuel in the tank and accumulated cost
    std::string Name;
    double Fuel_efficiency=10.00; //fuel efficiency is out of 100km so it basically tells how many litres it takes to travel 100km
    double Fuel_In_Tank;
    double Accumulated_Cost;
    const double Cost_Per_Litre = 1.30; // Assume the cost per litre of fuel is $1.30
    const double Tank_Capacity = 50.00;//Assume the tank capacity is 50.0L
public:
    Automobile();
    
    Err_Status Travel(double _distance);
    
};

#endif// _AUTOMOBILE_H_
```

I cannot declare the function travel as

```
Err_Status Automobile:: Travel(double _distance) {   //error C3861                  
    return Err_Status();                            //E0147 
  }
```

Hi, here is the useful build log

```
C:\Users\AutoLogon\OneDrive - Seneca\Documents\Seneca\Semester 2\SEP 200\WS10\Automobile.cpp(39,25): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'Automobile::Travel'
C:\Users\AutoLogon\OneDrive - Seneca\Documents\Seneca\Semester 2\SEP 200\WS10\Automobile.cpp(39,31): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\AutoLogon\OneDrive - Seneca\Documents\Seneca\Semester 2\SEP 200\WS10\Automobile.cpp(39,50): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\AutoLogon\OneDrive - Seneca\Documents\Seneca\Semester 2\SEP 200\WS10\Automobile.cpp(39,50): error C2556: 'int Automobile::Travel(double)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'Vehicle::Err_Status Automobile::Travel(double)'
C:\Users\AutoLogon\OneDrive - Seneca\Documents\Seneca\Semester 2\SEP 200\WS10\Automobile.h(35): message : see declaration of 'Automobile::Travel'
C:\Users\AutoLogon\OneDrive - Seneca\Documents\Seneca\Semester 2\SEP 200\WS10\Automobile.cpp(39,25): error C2371: 'Automobile::Travel': redefinition; different basic types
C:\Users\AutoLogon\OneDrive - Seneca\Documents\Seneca\Semester 2\SEP 200\WS10\Automobile.h(35): message : see declaration of 'Automobile::Travel'
```

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, besides showing us a [mre] also please include the full and complete build log, copy-pasted as text. Please [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Change `Err_Status Automobile::` to `Vehicle::Err_Status Automobile::`. See [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/1R-kjlnqH8)

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that to use `Err_Status` when specifying it in the return type of the member function we've to be in the scope of the containing class which is `Vehicle` in your example which we can do by qualifying `Err_Status` with `Vehicle` using the *scope resolution `operator::`*

So to **solve** this we can use `Vehicle::Err_Status` instead of just `Err_Status` when specifying the return type of the method as shown below:

```
vvvvvvvvv--------------------------------------------------> Vehicle:: added here
Vehicle::Err_Status Automobile:: Travel(double _distance) {                    
    return Err_Status();                            
 }
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/EEmq2nRti)